# WindowsのFormアプリ（C#.Net）でPictureBoxのスクロールバーが表示されない。

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10

WindowsのFormアプリ（C#.Net）で画像ビューワーを作っております。
Panelをウィンドウに貼り付け、そのPanelのサイズよりも大きい
PictureBoxをPanelの上に配置して、Panelのプロパティ「AutoScroll」を
「True」に設定しております。
希望の動作は、Panelから、はみ出た部分の画像をスクロールさせて
見せたいのですが、スクロールバーが表示されず困っております。
確認した方が良いプロパティやコードなどありましたら、
ご教授願いませんでしょうか。
宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: この記事 [スクロールバー付き PictureBox は Dock プロパティを設定しない](https://qiita.com/monta31538/items/a8c1138958712096a020) が一番まとまっていそうです。他にはこんなサンプルとか。[イメージをスクロール表示してマウスでドラッグ可能に](http://codepanic.itigo.jp/cs/picturebox_scroll.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントに紹介した記事はちょっと古いか名前ミスしているようです。
以下になるでしょう。

1. Panel.AutoScroll を True に、
2. PictureBox を Panel に貼り付け、
3. PictureBox.Location を (0, 0) に設定、**←これは必須ではなさそう**
4. **PictureBox に Panel.Size よりも大きなサイズの画像ファイルを選択して貼り付ける**
5. PictureBox.**SizeMode** を AutoSize に設定するか、
   **PictureBox.Size 値を (Panel.Size - スクロールバーサイズ)より大きく設定する**
6. そして PictureBox.Dock プロパティは None のまま。寝た子は起こさない、そっとしておく。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！
教えて頂いたとおりにやってみたのですが、
やっぱり表示されませんでした。
・Panel部品に「HScrolBar」、「VScrolBar」などを配置しておかないといけない
など、あったりしますでしょうか。

Comment: `Panel.AutoSize` を `True` にしているとダメなようです。デフォルトが `False` なので元に戻してみてください。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。試してみようと思ったのですが、仕様変更により、対応の必要がなくなりました。ありがとうございました。